# How can I run a long background process in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to run a background process when the user sends a form to an action, and tell him that the process was started and in ten minutes the data are updated. But I have some troubles.
In my action looks like this:

```
public function actualizarLineasAction()
    {
        $this->view->titulo = $this->_helper->x->lang("Actualizar el número de líneas de todos los clientes");
        if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
        {
            if($this->_getParam('start'))
            {
                $descriptorspec = array(
                    array('pipe', 'r'),
                    array('file', 'myfile.txt', 'a'),
                    array('pipe', 'w'),
                 );
               $proc = proc_open("php ".APPLICATION_PATH."/../scripts/update_clientes_lineas.php > ".APPLICATION_PATH."/../scripts/update_lines.log", $descriptorspec, $pipes);
               proc_close($proc);
                $this->view->message = $this->_helper->x->__("El proceso empezó en unos minutos habrá terminado y los contadores de líneas de los clientes estarán actualizados");

            }
        }
    }
```

The script file (In this script I want to parse and insert to data base a large file with 12500 lines with its validations and checks) so for test, a simple script:

```
<?php 
//It is only for test
for ($index = 1; $index < 1800; $index++) {
    $x = $index * 18;
    sleep(10);
}
echo "El resultado ".$x;
?>
```

I put into this script init's, define's and botstrap runs etc.. and I get the same result(Now I'm trying without they), this:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in <b>/homez.636/innovaco/fenix/public/index.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
```

Well I worried for the version the sever php , in the application through htaccess it's sets to 5_4 but in comand line I can't do it.

Is that the problem of this error? if not, What's going on?

What is the best way into Zend Framework to do a background process without maintain the client waiting for the response?

I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you very much!

Greetings.

Comment: Zend doesn't support PHP 4.

Comment: Yes, I know it, but I don't understand how affect this to zend application, I'm runnign a comand... Would you mean that if the server run in 5.4 this error doesn't appear and all it will work fine?

Comment: What is on line 9 of index.php?

Comment: $application->bootstrap()->run();

Comment: Okay, you can't chain object method calls (`bootstrap()->run()`) in PHP 4 so that's why you're getting that specific error, but a ZF app definitely won't run in PHP 4 anyway. Also, I'm pretty sure `proc_open` won't return until the script finishes.

Comment: Thank you Tim, you're right. I know that runs ZF app from PHP 4 it isn't possible, I was confused, because I'm running the command from an action which it's executing over PHP 5.4, and now I suppose that the script returns control under PHP 4.x and when the interpreter intent to parse this line it fails. Okay, after looking more closely this functions I agree with you and with Adrian and I will use exec(). I'm going to do more tests in localhost with exec() and PHP 5.4 in command line.

Comment: If your server has multiple versions of PHP you'll need to figure out the path to the PHP CLI for 5.4. Then instead of calling `exec('php ...')` you call `exec('/path/to/php5.4/php ...')`. You might need to check this with your host.

Comment: Yes it has, but I talked with the support of our hosting and they told me that in command line I can't run it "as include path version". But I can get information about path with some commands from php 5.4, because the zf app change through htaccess the version ,it wants say I can do what you say. Is a good way to get it. Thank you Tim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a background process I'd use [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

In the PHP manual see the **Notes** section and the first white note

> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

You can find a few examples below in the user contributed part.

Comment: Thank you Adrian, I've readed more closely the docs and you're right. I'm going to do it with exec().

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I can run PHP 5.3 under command line, and with the exec() function I could to do it. All works fine, I run a background process which takes around twelve minutes in finalize and the user is redirect to another view to wait the results of the process when it ends.

```
exec("php.5.3 ".APPLICATION_PATH."/../scripts/update_clientes_lineas.php  > ".APPLICATION_PATH."/../scripts/update.log 2>&1 &");
//2>&1 redirect STDERR to STDOUT and STDOUT to /null, & allows to run a process in background.
```

Thank you very much Tim and Adrian, your answers were very useful!